# Error initializing SQLite database located in my home folder

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I get the below error when I try to connect to the database. I have given all the permissions to all users on my machine. Is there something else I need to do on Xcode?

> Error initializing SQLite database: The operation couldn’t be completed. (SQLite.Result error 0.)

This is my code:

```swift
class SQLiteManager { 
    static let shared = SQLiteManager()
    private var db: Connection? 
    private init() { // Initialize database connection
        do {
            let dbPath = "/Users/mrx/desktop/testdb.db"
            db = try Connection(dbPath)
            print("SQLite database path: (dbPath)")
        } catch {
            print("Error initializing SQLite database: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

I have given all the permissions to all users on my machine using chmod for the db file, is there something else I need to do on Xcode?

I was thinking it must be a permission issue, but doesn't seem like it. It work's fine when I open the connection for database on the device (iPhone). but when I try to connectto local database, it throws error.

Comment: it could be due to the [Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-the-macos-app-sandbox)

Comment: iOS app. using Xcode

Comment: AFAIK,  in iOS SQLite database is stored locally within the app's sandbox directory.
 In your case in Xcode you are trying to read a file from the "/Users/mrx/desktop/testdb.db",
 you probably need to get permission for that, or remove the Sandbox.

Comment: Why are you trying to read a file from your Mac's file system while running an iOS app? The only files your iOS app has access to are files in its sandbox, including its resources.

Comment: okay, thanks. I'm new to iOS dev, how do I save the data from that app that I'm developing to a local database?